# Lambda function: Amazon S3 API get-bucket-tagging getting permission error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I want to get S3 bucket object tags in my AWS Lambda function (python 3.6 environment). I am getting object tags successfully on my local environment but when I run it in AWS lambda function I receive the error:

> "errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObjectTagging operation: Access Denied","

Although I have created IAM role with all the writes on s3 bucket and objects.

IAM role policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elastictranscoder:*",
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Code is:

```
python
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = 'bucket_name'
key = 'SampleVideo_360x240_2mb (1)----swae.mp4'
response = s3.get_object_tagging(
        Bucket=bucket,
         Key=key,
     )
tag_set = response.get("TagSet")
print(tag_set)
```

Comment: I think "*" gets removed here, you need to check if Lambda has the exact role attached to it, if so, check if bucket is in same account, if yes, are they any deny statement in it.

Answer (score 0):

To test this situation, I did the following:

- Created an IAM Role with the permissions you provided as an Inline Policy
- Created an AWS Lambda function with your code (but used my own Bucket and Key)

The Lambda code was within a function:

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    bucket = 'my-bucket'
    key = 'foo.jpg'
    response = s3.get_object_tagging(
            Bucket=bucket,
             Key=key,
         )
    tag_set = response.get("TagSet")
    print(tag_set)
```

I invoked the function as a Test and it ran successfully and produced this output:

```
START RequestId: 9e21b6b5-5456-4ec7-9488-0c11c1d52fca Version: $LATEST
[{'Key': 'cheese', 'Value': 'gruyere'}]
END RequestId: 9e21b6b5-5456-4ec7-9488-0c11c1d52fca
REPORT RequestId: 9e21b6b5-5456-4ec7-9488-0c11c1d52fca  Duration: 1218.70 ms    Billed Duration: 1300 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 60 MB
```

So, it all ran okay for me!

Comment: My example is working now with real events. but upon testing it still gives the same error i think i was giving error because i have attached so many useless IAM  policies.

Comment: If it work "with real events", but not in testing, check the test data that you have configured in the Lambda console. You can specify the Bucket and Key in the test data to point to your own files. You might be receiving the error because your test data is pointing at a bucket that is not in your account.